# How to import multiple values for a property from csv file in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, csv-import

I am facing an issue with importing multiple values for a property of node from csv file.
For example we have below values in csv file,

| CarDriver | Passengers |
| --- | --- |
| Ganesh | Rajesh |
| Ganesh | Sunil |
| Ganesh | Mangesh |
| Suresh | Mukesh |
| Suresh | Nitesh |

Can anyone please suggest some solution for this issue?

Thanks,
Santosh

I tried to modify my query as per below two solutions from stackoverflow but it did not work,

It gave me below error, "Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'id': (:Person {id: null})".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/sjamale/Adaptive/neo4j/neo4j-enterprise-4.4.19/import/Accident_Insurance_Fraud_Detection.csv" AS row
WITH row WHERE row.`Accident_Car_Driver` is NOT NULL
MERGE (n:`Persons` {UID : "CarDriver_" + row.`Accident_Car_Driver`})
SET n.AccidentCarDriver = row.`Accident_Car_Driver`,
n.AccidentCarPassenger = row.`Accident_Car_Passengers`,
n.CarOwner = row.`Accident_Car_Owner`,
n.Container = "Health Insurance Fraud";


Above is code used for importing.

Comment: Sorry this is old and likely you have solved it, but I think this is more about the structure of your graph. I think you need relationship between :CarDriver nodes and :Passenger nodes.